# A copy to clipboard dashboard button

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard

How can I make a "copy to clipboard" button in a dashboard widget?

<del>An example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfdgGFrrmIQ</del>

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Fran, while there is similarity between the questions, doing this in a dashboard widget does have different challenges. So, technically the linked answer (400212) wouldn't always work. Some solutions might but I think it's a fair separate question on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `widget.system` method.

Example: `widget.system("/bin/echo '"+password+"' | /usr/bin/pbcopy", null);`

For this to work, under Widget Attributes, you must enable Command Line Access (Checkbox "Allow Command Line Access"

Source: http://andrew.hedges.name/widgets/dev/ under 'System Access'